# Is it possible to pass logged in user credentials to WCF services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, soa, wif

I currently have a service layer which is exposed via WCF. The service layer includes private endpoints that are to be accessed internally using the TCP protocol but also includes public endpoints (API) for some services to be accessed publicly via HTTP. So far so good... My problem is I don't know how to implement authentication and authorization correctly.

Question 1: If I have an asp.net application that uses asp.net Identity for authentication (Forms Based Authentication) and authorization. Is it possible to pass in those credentials to the WCF service automatically i.e. so that I can perform role based authorization on each service within my service layer? If this is indeed possible can someone provide me with some sample code or point me in the right direction for further reading? If it is not possible? Is there an alternative solution?

Question 2: Do I need two separate databases? i.e. one database for the web application that contains all the users, roles etc and then another database for my service layer that contains all the business data of the application?

Comment: had look at these? - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398990(v=vs.140).aspx and http://dotnetspeak.com/2012/01/securing-wcf-with-forms-authentication